# What is up with all the close votes?

Tags: discussion, questions, vote-to-close

It seems like there are always a bunch of questions in the close vote queue.  As a Moderator, my vote has more weight, so I try to stay out of the queue completely.

One of the questions (currently with 3 close votes) is [How can spirocerca lupi worms be killed in a dog?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/11485) it seems like a reasonable question to me. I don't personally know anything about it so I just Googled and found the below.  Which implies the question asked is completely valid.  If my pet had been diagnosed with the condition, I would look to a site where pet experts answered questions for the best answer.

So why is it that our community is trying to close this and other questions from pet owners?

> In endemic areas, dogs should be prevented from eating dung beetles, frogs, mice, lizards, etc, and not fed raw chicken scraps. In Europe, monthly treatment with topical moxidectin/imidacloprid is approved for use in dogs as a preventive for S lupi infection. Treatment of clinical cases is often not practical. However, efficacy has been demonstrated with doramectin (0.2 mg/kg, SC, three doses at 2-wk intervals; 0.4 mg/kg, SC, six doses at 2-wk intervals; 0.5 mg/kg, SC, two doses 2 wk apart; 0.5 mg/kg/day, PO, for 42 days; 0.8 mg/kg, SC, two doses 1 wk apart; additional treatments may be required), and ivermectin (0.6 mg/kg, SC, two doses 2 wk apart) combined with prednisolone (0.5 mg/kg, PO, bid for 2 wk and then tapered), although none of these treatments is approved. The specific breed toxicity associated with ivermectin in Collies and other herding dog breeds also occurs with doramectin. Surgical removal usually is unsuccessful because of the large areas of the esophagus involved.

[Source](http://www.merckvetmanual.com/mvm/digestive_system/gastrointestinal_parasites_of_small_animals/spirocerca_lupi_in_small_animals.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Questions shouldn't be closed just because we don't think the relevant expert is here *now*. The set of pet experts includes vets, some of whom might be here (now or later). Most SE sites have some "long-tail" questions, specific questions that require a particular expertise that might take some time to get answered. *That's ok.* It's why questions remain open even after the asker accepts an answer -- we don't shut down future contributions.

I recently asked a [question](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/13437/31) requiring expertise in disease transmission.  I didn't expect to get an answer here quickly, though I'd be delighted if I did.  I've already asked my vet; she has to do research too.  But the question is on-topic and by asking it here I just *might* reach that expert out there somewhere on the Internet who can help me.  Stack Exchange is, in part, for expert answers to hard questions.

Answer (score -1):

Unless there's a veterinarian in the site I doubt anyone else can answer the question you link, I think it's a too specialized topic and probably out of range of our knowledge.

***But you could research and post an answer based on that research!***

Indeed we could've but so can OP, which makes the question look with a lack of effort and research.

I personally voted to close that question as too broad, since me, a common user with poor knowledge in the veterinarian field didn't even know about that disease since none of my dogs has gotten it. There's no explanation as to why the question was asked, there's no brief explanation of the disease either. And personally, I think OP should've included information about his/her particular case; how old is the dog, for how long has the dog had the disease. Helps bring more content and context to the question.

Comment: You can use comments to ask for clarification from the OP.

Comment: Part one of my answer still applies, we simply don't have the knowledge to answer that question. Why get information from OP if we won't be able to solve his problem?

Comment: Part one, because StackExchange sites are supposed to be the place to get answers from experts.  We are supposed to be a community of pet experts.  Voting to close a question because you don't know the answer and don't want to research it does not feel like a good way to support the site.

Comment: **PET** experts, not veterinarians, and please do check my answer history, I do research for answers when I know I can get the answer through research but the answer for the question at hand requires more than just a google search, we don't know how to advise OP regarding this particular and specialized situation.

Comment: I know for a fact that veterinarians visit our site.  How are they going to answer the question if it is closed? Or perhaps a veterinarian student who is doing research?  I often post a comment asking for more information from the OP when I know it will be needed to answer the question, but I will not be able to answer the question.

Comment: If you're not going to be able to answer the question then how do you know what information is needed to answer it? And it's good news we have veterinarians in the house, maybe after they comment and get the information they need they can ask for a reopen vote. We can't keep every question open just for the sake that someone "might" come and answer it.

Comment: And asking for information when you don't even plan to answer a question is a much more bad practice than casting a close vote when needed. You just raise OP's hopes in vain.

Comment: While I don't agree with all your ideas, I thank you for sharing them. The lack of activity on this and other meta posts worries me.

Comment: Yeah I agree, it looks more like a fight rather than an argument/discussion, since it's only two of us actually participating

Comment: tbh, I don't mind doing research and posting it for folks because I'm pretty knowledgeable in reading scientific sources and summarizing them for a lay audience (at least, I think so), so I voted to leave it open. I just haven't had time recently because of personal stuff.

Comment: I don't mind doing it either, when I know I can get a complete answer researching by myself and I've answered a couple of questions through research @Zaralynda